# WD Elements 1042 with usb 3.0, Windows 7

Tags: windows

I have a WD Elements 1042 with usb 3.0, Windows 7, Lenovo notebook and My Computer can't see it.

Anyway, it's visible in Hardware and Sound -> Devices and Printers -> Elements 1042 Properties -> WD Elements 1042 USB Device Properties: Driver Provider: Microsoft / Driver Date 6/21/2006 / Driver Version: 6.1.7600.16385 / Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows.

The Update Driver button is off.

When I go to the Device Manager -> Disk Drives -> WD Elements 1042 USB Device and I try to update the driver, they tell me "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date."

Even so, the hdd is not recognized as an external drive by Windows and not appearing in My Computer. Can please anybody tell me why is that? Thanks!!

Comment: Does the disk appear in Windows' Disk Management console?  Does it have partitions on it, and has it been formatted with a file system Windows recognizes?

Comment: Have you checked if the drive is listed in Disk Management? Is it working fine when connected to a different system? If it isn't showing under Disk Management there might be a problem with the drive. You can use WD DLG to test it : http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=xCHHfK . You can also try using a different USB 3.0 cable and connecting it to a different USB 3.0 port. Those drives are power fed trough the USB cable so it's important that the cable you use is a short one and of good quality.